# How do I remove TOTAL EXCL TAX from cart review page?

Tags: checkout, orders, cart, tax

In Magento by default the review page displays the Cart TOTAL EXCL TAX and Cart TOTAL INCL TAX.

Due to the way I've configured Magento (everything including tax), the EXCL TAX and INCL TAX values are identical (which could be confusing for customers).

Does anyone know of a way to remove the EXCL TAX line from the cart review page?
(I can't seem to find a configuration option for it anywhere).

Answer (score 3):

Found how to do this (programatically)....

Under *{magento_base}/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/tax/checkout/*

Edit file **grandtotal.phtml**

(I suggest you make a backup of the file just in case).

Find the line:

```
<?php if ($this->includeTax() && $this->getTotalExclTax()>=0):?>
```

Delete the subsequent lines:

```
<tr>
    <td style="<?php echo $this->getStyle() ?>" class="a-right" colspan="<?php echo $this->getColspan(); ?>">
        <strong><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Grand Total Excl. Tax')?></strong>
    </td>
    <td style="<?php echo $this->getStyle() ?>" class="a-right">
        <strong><?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($this->getTotalExclTax()) ?></strong>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This change means it will now only show the tax inclusive line in the cart review.

Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: Please don't change `base/default` make this changes in your custom theme

Answer (score 0):

Please check if changing the below store configuration solve this. So we can avoid a code change.

[image]

Which renders the totals as below

[image]

`./vendor/magento/module-tax/view/frontend/templates/checkout/grandtotal.phtml`
In this file, the totals INCL and EXCL both loaded only when this condition is satisfied.

```
<?php if ($block->includeTax() && $block->getTotalExclTax() >= 0):?>
```

And the includeTax() method check the above-described store configuration value. Switch this "Include Tax in Order Total" to NO in both

`Store > Configuration > Tax > Shopping Cart Display Settings = NO`

`Store > Configuration > Tax > Orders, Invoices, Credit Memos Display Settings = NO`